# Track Performance Robot Framework with stopwatch

Tags: performance, selenium, robotframework

I would like to track the performance with Robot Framework & Selenium2Library. When I click on an element a stopwatch must be counting en stops when the page is ready. Is it possible? I'm known with the DateTime library and tried something but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple example which measures the time that the page took to load some distinct element:

```
${start} =  Get Current Date
Open Browser    https://ixquick.com/
Wait Until Page Contains Element    //input[@id='query']
${stop} =   Get Current Date
${diff} =   Subtract Date From Date     ${stop}     ${start}
Log    ${diff}
```

You need `Selenium2Library` and `DateTime` library to run this. Adjust it to your needs, i.e. you have to find a *definition of ready*. This might be some HTML element to be present or some other criteria.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i mean. In combination with this [Library](http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/)  i can made easy a performance report in excel.